# What does bare strings in the body of a class definition mean?

Tags: python

Here is a snippet of code from `django.core.exceptions`:

```
class MiddlewareNotUsed(Exception):
    "This middleware is not used in this server configuration"
    pass
```

Is the bare string in the body of the class a mere literal for documentation ? Or does it perform some magic ?

Comment: Please do not stay away from them. Docstrings are one of my favorite python features. 1) They allow easy documentation. 2) In the interpreter, the doc-string of an object/function can be accessed with `my_object.__doc__` making learning a new library much easier. 3) They allow for simple unit tests with the docttest module.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a [doc string](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/):

> A docstring is a string literal that occurs as the first statement
>   in a module, function, class, or method definition. Such a docstring
>   becomes the `__doc__` special attribute of that object.
>
> All modules should normally have docstrings, and all functions and
>   classes exported by a module should also have docstrings. Public
>   methods (including the `__init__` constructor) should also have
>   docstrings. A package may be documented in the module docstring of the
>   `__init__.py` file in the package directory.

Comment: You might also want to add *why* you should have docstrings. Like the ability for automated tests with the [`doctest`](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html) module.

Answer (score 2):

It's a [docstring](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#documentation-strings). The only magic is that it ends up on the object as `__doc__`.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a [docstring](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-docstrings).